# Dropdown not reseting after changing value

Tags: flutter

The dropdown is not updating as expected when setting `_municipality` to `null` since the last selected value is still active. In other words, the dropdown does not get unselected as it should do.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class CivilRegistrationDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CivilRegistrationDialogState createState() =>
      _CivilRegistrationDialogState();
}

class _CivilRegistrationDialogState extends State<CivilRegistrationDialog> {
  List<String> _municipalities = [];
  String _municipality;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchMunicipalities();
  }

  void _fetchMunicipalities() async {
    final uri = Uri.https('skatteverket.se', 'st-api/rest/v1/kommuner');
    final response = await http.get(uri);

    final data = json.decode(response.body);
    final municipalities = List<String>.from(data['2018']);

    setState(() => _municipalities = municipalities);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: const Text('Folkbokföring'),
      content: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          const Text(
            'Välj din folkbokföringsort samt om du är medlem i en församling.',
          ),
          DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
            onChanged: (municipality) => setState(
              () => _municipality = municipality,
            ),
            items: _municipalities
                .map((municipality) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      child: Text(municipality),
                      value: municipality,
                    ))
                .toList(),
            value: _municipality,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() => _municipality = null);
          },
          child: const Text('ÅNGRA VAL'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a know issue and has been fixed in the `beta` channel. Should be merged into `stable` soon.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56898

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code. On my machine the dropdown got unselected as i pressed FlatButton as you want. So just try to hotrestart instead of hotreload.

Comment: Not working even after a full app restart. Can I have something to do with it being a dialog? Also, what flutter version are you on?